# Signal SIGABRT regularly when running Swift app in Xcode

Tags: ios, swift, nstimer

I'm just starting to learn some ios development in Xcode and I am following an online tutorial. It seems though that very regularly my app crashes when I run it and I get the dreaded Signal SIGABRT error.

For example, I have this code:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBAction func camera(_ sender: Any) {
        print("hello")
    }

    func processTimer() {
        print("a second has passed!")
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        var timer = Timer()

        timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1, target: self, selector: Selector("processTimer"), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }
}
```

Now, prior to adding the timer part, the app opened fine. As soon as I added the timer, it creates this crash. The only way I seem to be able to resolve is by deleting the button, but obviously as I start to create proper apps, this will be a real pain.

This same thing has happened a lot to me already where the app works, I add some code and then suddenly I get this error. Could somebody explain what it is I am doing wrong here and how I can fix without deleting the button each time?

Comment: That's some pretty out-of-date Swift code. What version of Xcode and Swift are you trying to use?

Comment: Oh really? I'm on 10.2.1

Comment: Is the `@IBAction` hooked up correctly?

Comment: You need to mark `processTimer` as `@objc` in order to use as a selector, but your `Selector` syntax shows that you're using quite an old Swift version, so you should specify which one. You should also make sure the `timer` is actually stored in memory and released before you invalidate it, so you should store it as an instance property rather than a local variable.